# Why does it get same value?? and how to attach currency sign after result?

Tags: javascript, html

Why does it get same value?? and how to attach currency sign after result?
also, How to make it more briefly? I want to amend the repeating code.

```js
function changeSign() {
  var currencySelect = document.getElementById("CurrencyID").value;
}

function changeCurrency() {

  var inputVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inputMoney").value);
  var currencyVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inputMoney"));

  if (document.getElementById("Euro")) {

    if (document.getElementById("Us1")) {

      currencyVal = (inputVal * 1.08);

    } else if (document.getElementById("Uk1")) {

      currencyVal = (inputVal * 0.83);

    } else if (document.getElementById("Ja1")) {

      currencyVal = (inputVal * 118.88);

    } else if (document.getElementById("Ca1")) {

      currencyVal = (inputVal * 1.43);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = currencyVal;
}
```

```html
<b>Choose Convert : </b><br><br>
<select name="CurrencyConverter" id="CurrencyID" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 200px; height:30px;" onchange="changeSign()">
  <option id="Euro" value="&euro;">Euro (EUR)</option>
  <option id="Us" value="&dollar;">US Dollar (USD)</option>
  <option id="Uk" value="&pound;">UK Pound Sterling (GBP)</option>
  <option id="Ja" value="&yen;">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
  <option id="Ca" value="&#36;">Canadian Dollor (CAD)</option>
</select>
<br>

<b>Choose Convert : </b><br><br>
<select name="CurrencyConverter" id="CurrencyID" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 200px; height:30px;">
  <option id="Euro1" value="&euro;">Euro (EUR)</option>
  <option id="Us1" value="&dollar;">US Dollar (USD)</option>
  <option id="Uk1" value="&pound;">UK Pound Sterling (GBP)</option>
  <option id="Ja1" value="&yen;">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
  <option id="Ca1" value="&#36;">Canadian Dollor (CAD)</option>
</select>
<br>

<label>
                <br>
                <input name="inputMoney" id="inputMoney" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
                    style="width: 196px; height:22px;" oninput="changeCurrency()"
                    >
            </label><br><br>

</div>
</div>

<p>value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("Us1")` will check if the element with a given ID exists, not that it's filled in with data. Since it exists on the page, you always go inside the first `if` and skip the rest of the branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly; Id properties have to be unique in html files. check your id props and give different names.
Then get values with document.getElementById("CurrencyID1").value and check their values in if conditions.

check the following solution:

```js
function changeSign() {
  var currencySelect = document.getElementById("CurrencyID1").value;
}

function changeCurrency() {
    let firstCurrency = document.getElementById("CurrencyID1").value;
    let secondCurrency = document.getElementById("CurrencyID2").value;
    
    let inputVal = document.getElementById("inputMoney").value;
    let currencyVal=0;
            
   if (firstCurrency==="euro") {
      if (secondCurrency==="usd") {
        currencyVal = (inputVal * 1.08)+" $";
      } else if (secondCurrency==="pound") {
        currencyVal = (inputVal * 0.83)+" £";
      } else if (secondCurrency==="yen") {
        currencyVal = (inputVal * 118.88)+" ¥";
      } else if (secondCurrency==="can") {
        currencyVal = (inputVal * 1.43)+ " $";
      }
    }
     

  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = currencyVal;
}
```

```html
<b>Choose Convert : </b><br><br>
<select id="CurrencyID1" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"          style="width: 200px; height:30px;" onchange="changeSign()">
  <option id="Euro" value="euro">Euro (EUR)</option>
  <option id="Us" value="usd">US Dollar (USD)</option>
  <option id="Uk" value="pound">UK Pound Sterling (GBP)</option>
  <option id="Ja" value="yen">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
  <option id="Ca" value="can">Canadian Dollor (CAD)</option>
</select>
<br>

<b>Choose Convert : </b><br><br>
<select id="CurrencyID2" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 200px; height:30px;">
  <option id="Euro1" value="euro">Euro (EUR)</option>
  <option id="Us1" value="usd">US Dollar (USD)</option>
  <option id="Uk1" value="pound">UK Pound Sterling (GBP)</option>
  <option id="Ja1" value="yen">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
  <option id="Ca1" value="can">Canadian Dollor (CAD)</option>
</select>
<br>

<label>
   <br>
  <input name="inputMoney" id="inputMoney" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 196px; height:22px;" oninput="changeCurrency()">
            </label><br><br>
 

<p>value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

Comment: Thank you @AbdurrahmanY. Is it impossible to put the sign in the label box when I select the any country currency??

Comment: sorry what do you mean label box? I did not understand

Comment: In the text box.

Comment: also label tag in your html is doing nothing. remove it nothing will change

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will try it.

Comment: or maybe you can create a empty label before the textbox and after selecting the first currency you can set it with the proper currency.

Answer (score 0):

**Your condition
Problem giving. Try as below**

```
<b>Choose Convert : </b><br><br>
            <select name="CurrencyConverter" id="CurrencyID" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
                style="width: 200px; height:30px;">
                <option id="Euro1" value="Euro1">Euro (EUR)</option>
                <option id="Us1" value="Us1">US Dollar (USD)</option>
                <option id="Uk1" value="Uk1">UK Pound Sterling (GBP)</option>
                <option id="Ja1" value="Ja1">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
                <option id="Ca1" value="Ca1">Canadian Dollor (CAD)</option>
            </select>
            <br>

            <label>
                <br>
                <input name="inputMoney" id="inputMoney" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
                    style="width: 196px; height:22px;" oninput="changeCurrency()"
                    >
            </label><br><br>

        </div>
    </div>
```

*js*

```
    function changeCurrency() {


    var currencySelect = document.getElementById("CurrencyID").value; 

    var inputVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inputMoney").value);
    var currencyVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inputMoney"));

    if (document.getElementById("Euro")) {

        if (currencySelect == "Us1") {

            currencyVal = (inputVal * 1.08);

        } else if (currencySelect == "Uk1") {

            currencyVal = (inputVal * 0.83);

        } else if (currencySelect == "Ja1") {

            currencyVal = (inputVal * 118.88);

        } else if (currencySelect == "Ca1") {

            currencyVal = (inputVal * 1.43);
        }

}
```

Comment: Thx. But I need a value as a currency sign in order to plus next currencyVal.

Answer (score 0):

**html**

**Choose Convert :** 
        
            Euro (EUR)
            US Dollar (USD)
            UK Pound Sterling (GBP)
            Japanese Yen (JPY)
            Canadian Dollor (CAD)

```
    <b>Choose Convert : </b><br><br>
    <select name="CurrencyConverter" id="convartToCurrencyID" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 200px; height:30px;">
        <option id="Euro1" value="Euro1">Euro (EUR)</option>
        <option id="Us1" value="Us1">US Dollar (USD)</option>
        <option id="Uk1" value="Uk1">UK Pound Sterling (GBP)</option>
        <option id="Ja1" value="Ja1">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
        <option id="Ca1" value="Ca1">Canadian Dollor (CAD)</option>
    </select>
    <br>

            <label>
                <br>
                <input name="inputMoney" id="inputMoney" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 196px; height:22px;" oninput="changeCurrency()" >
            </label><br><br>

</div>
</div>

<p>value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

**js code**

```
function changeCurrency() {

    var currencySelect = document.getElementById("CurrencyID").value;
    var convartToCurrencyID = document.getElementById("convartToCurrencyID").value;

  var inputVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inputMoney").value);
  var currencyVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inputMoney"));

        if (currencySelect == "Us1" && convartToCurrencyID == "Us1") {

        currencyVal = (inputVal * 1);

        } else if (currencySelect == "Us1" && convartToCurrencyID == "Uk1") {

        currencyVal = (inputVal * 0.83);

        } else if (currencySelect == "Us1" && convartToCurrencyID == "Ja1") {

        currencyVal = (inputVal * 118.88);

        } else if (currencySelect == "Us1" && convartToCurrencyID == "Ca1") {

        currencyVal = (inputVal * 1.43);
        }

  document.getElementById("demo").textContent = currencyVal;
}
```

**This way you will have to adjust the condition for all of them**

**Now lets see that all will be convart from USD**

Answer (score 0):

1- you are not getting value of select's
2- you need InnerHTML not inner text
3- I guess simple map would be better than if elses

```js
function changeSign() {
  var currencySelect = document.getElementById("CurrencyID").value;
}

function changeCurrency() {

  var inputVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("inputMoney").value);
  var exchange={"euro;euro;":1,
"euro;dollar;":1.08,"euro;pound;":0.83,"euro;yen;":1118.88,"euro;#36;":1.43
};
var ev=document.getElementById("CurrencyID1").value+document.getElementById("CurrencyID2").value;
currencyVal=exchange[ev] *inputVal;   

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = currencyVal +" &"+document.getElementById("CurrencyID2").value;
}
```

```html
<b>Choose Convert : </b><br><br>
<select name="CurrencyConverter" id="CurrencyID1" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 200px; height:30px;" onchange="changeSign()">
  <option id="Euro" value="euro;">Euro (EUR)</option>
  <option id="Us" value="dollar;">US Dollar (USD)</option>
  <option id="Uk" value="pound;">UK Pound Sterling (GBP)</option>
  <option id="Ja" value="yen;">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
  <option id="Ca" value="#36;">Canadian Dollor (CAD)</option>
</select>
<br>

<b>Choose Convert : </b><br><br>
<select name="CurrencyConverter" id="CurrencyID2" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 200px; height:30px;">
  <option id="Euro1" value="euro;">Euro (EUR)</option>
  <option id="Us1" value="dollar;">US Dollar (USD)</option>
  <option id="Uk1" value="pound;">UK Pound Sterling (GBP)</option>
  <option id="Ja1" value="yen;">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
  <option id="Ca1" value="#36;">Canadian Dollor (CAD)</option>
</select>
<br>

<label>
                <br>
                <input name="inputMoney" id="inputMoney" type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
                    style="width: 196px; height:22px;" oninput="changeCurrency()"
                    >
            </label><br><br>

</div>
</div>

<p>value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to give you a cleaner solution:

**Note:** 
The `CurrencyList` object contains the implementation of the conversion for each respective currency to the other. So I have only worked out the Parsing of Euro to other currencies you've listed. So You might have to do this for every currency on the list.

```js
var CurrencyList = {
  Euro: {
    sign: '&euro;',
    Parse: function(value, desiredCurrency)
    {
      var result = 0;
      switch(desiredCurrency)
      {
        case 'Us': { result = value * 1.08 + CurrencyList[desiredCurrency].sign; } 
          break;
        case 'Uk': { result = value * 0.83 + CurrencyList[desiredCurrency].sign; }
          break;
        case 'Ja': { result = value * 118.88 + CurrencyList[desiredCurrency].sign; }
          break;
        case 'Ca': { result = value * 1.43 + CurrencyList[desiredCurrency].sign; }
          break;
      }
      return result;
    }
  },
  Uk: {
    sign: '&pound;'
  },
  Us: {
    sign: '&dollar;'
  },
  Ja: {
    sign: '&yen;'
  },
  Ca: {
    sign: '&#36;'
  }
};

document.getElementById("fromCurrencyID").addEventListener('change',
  function()
  {
    document.querySelector(".text-field__label").innerHTML = CurrencyList[document.getElementById("fromCurrencyID").value].sign;
  }
);

document.getElementById("convertButton")
  .addEventListener('click',
  function()
  {
    var _fromCurrency = document.getElementById("fromCurrencyID").value;
    var _toCurrency = document.getElementById("toCurrencyID").value;
    
    if(_fromCurrency && _toCurrency)
    {
      
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = CurrencyList[_fromCurrency].Parse(document.querySelector(".text-field__input").value,_toCurrency); 
    }
  }
);
```

```css
.text-field{
  width: 218px;
  height: 32px;
  padding-left: 22px;
}

.text-field .text-field_part{
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: thin solid #cdcdcd;
  display: block;
}

.text-field .text-field__label{
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.text-field .text-field__input {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<b>Choose Convert : </b><br><br>
<select name="CurrencyConverter" id="fromCurrencyID" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 200px; height:30px;">
  <option value="Euro">Euro (EUR)</option>
  <option value="Us">US Dollar (USD)</option>
  <option value="Uk">UK Pound Sterling (GBP)</option>
  <option value="Ja">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
  <option value="Ca">Canadian Dollor (CAD)</option>
</select>
<br>

<b>Choose Convert : </b><br><br>
<select name="CurrencyConverter" id="toCurrencyID" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 200px; height:30px;">
  <option value="Euro">Euro (EUR)</option>
  <option value="Us">US Dollar (USD)</option>
  <option value="Uk">UK Pound Sterling (GBP)</option>
  <option value="Ja">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option>
  <option value="Ca">Canadian Dollor (CAD)</option>
</select>
<br>

<label>
<br>
<div class="text-field">
  <button class="text-field__label text-field_part"></button>
  <input name="inputMoney" class="text-field__input text-field_part" type="text"
    style="width: 196px; height:32px;" />
</div>
</label><br><br>
<button id="convertButton">Convert</button>

<p>value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```